# Can't Run Android Emulator on VS Code using React Native

Tags: react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL0Gj.png)[ERROR MESSAGE: error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzBdZ.png)